# High Availability in PostgreSQL with automated failover

Tags: replication, clustering, postgresql-9.3, high-availability, performance, postgresql-performance

I am currently working on designing an architecture for High Availability in PostgreSQL for a database of approximately 5TB in size. Also, I would like to re-direct my reads to a slave node(preferably SR & Hot Standby) as every hour there are bulk imports. After my research, I have come up with three possible architectures, but would like to know how do I handle STONITH in these cases and also the best suitable of the three methods,

1) Pgpool2 (with HA) --> Master --> Slave (SR & HS)

2) Clustering with Pacemaker + Corosync + DRBD (for a 5 TB database) Performance?

3) PGPOOL2(with HA) + REPMGR

Comment: Rather than relying on PgPool-II's read-only query routing, if at all possible have the *application* understand which queries are read-only and should go to the replica.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Thanks you for your reply.. I am an Administrator and not good at App Server. Trying to figure out solutions as a DBA. Would like to shard data using Pl/proxy and use Londiste to replicate between Postgres, hoping its possible. Googled, but did not find material to integrate both. Any inputs/ideas from your end..?